# a shell script to copy a folder and all it's subfolders, but noit it's files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I need a shell script to copy a folder and all it's subfolders, but not any of it's files. The more portable (osx, linux, cygwin) the solution is, the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give this a try:

```
rsync -av -f"+ */" -f"- *" /path/src /path/dest/
```

Comment: This has the potential to copy across machine boundaries, which my solution does not.

Comment: @chepner what do you mean "across machine boundaries"? btw, yours is nice, but you may want to `cd /home/alice/prj` before execute your find cmd. or you could use `printf` to handle the found dir name a bit. otherwise it may do something like `mkdir -p /home/bob/home/alice/project/foo`.

Comment: My comment wasn't well-phrased. You're right about needing to modify the found path value for the call to `mkdir`; in light of your solution, it's not really worth fixing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This may seem like a small thing for you but it will be very, very useful to me! :)